# Recursive Call API With Loops

Tags: node.js, api, recursion, tail-recursion

Recently I was working with API calls and having more calls based on the previous calls return obj. For example, I start with a single API call of a 'friend' where its return statement is other friends. For each one of those friends, I want to get their friends and so forth until I get a list of all the friends.

A pseudocode example is as follows:

```
var someGlobalFriendArray = []; // Is a list of every friend's data. Like name, location, age, etc.

getFriends(oneFriendPath) {
        oneFriendPath.get()
        .then((friendData) => {
                if (friendData.empty) {
                        return;
                }
                someGlobalFriendArray.push(friendData) // Gets the data of each friend.
                friendData.friends.forEach(eachFriend => {
                        getFriends(eachFriend)
                })
        })
}

getFriends(startingFriend).then(() => console.log(someGlobalFriendArray))
```

I currently do not have a direct need for this but I was curious as to how I would be able to do this using Node.js specifically.

Comment: This sounds like [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)/[depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: Yeah it's the same as both breadth first search and depth first search. But I was wondering how I would be able to incorporate it with promises that would store the values.